# d3 update bar chart when data change

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new in d3 and I want to update my bar chart when the data change. A part of my d3 function is

```
var control = svg.selectAll(".control")
       .data(data)
       .enter().append("g")
       .attr("class", "g")
       .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Control) + ",0)"; });

       control.selectAll("rect")
       .data(function(d) { return d.category; })
       .enter().append("rect")
       .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
       .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
       .attr("height", 0)
       .attr("y", height)
       .on('mouseover', tip.show)
       .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
       .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

       control.selectAll("rect")
              .transition()
              .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 100; })
              .duration(1000)
              .attr("height", function(d, i) { if(columnNum == 2 && i == 2) return height - y1(d.value); else return height - y0(d.value); })
              .attr("y", function(d, i) { if(columnNum == 2 && i == 2) return y1(d.value); else return y0(d.value); });
```

I can see that the figure reads the updated data because it shows the tooltip for the updated data but the bar doesn't reflects these changes (e.g. a bar with 100 updated to 50, I will have 2 tooltips but original bar still fill with 100?)

Any idea on how to update/add new/ delete bars? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you may be handling the enter/update selections incorrectly. Could you provide a complete working example please?

Comment: I tried to use jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/HLzbE/1) but couldn't make it work. Anyhow the complete example is there. Hope this is fine! @LarsKotthoff

Comment: Can't really help you without the data I'm afraid.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff How about now? http://jsfiddle.net/HLzbE/4 Thank you for your help!

Comment: You saved only the enter selection in `control` -- save the entire selection. You're also setting the wrong class. I've fixed those [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HLzbE/5/), but there are a couple of other problems (axes, legends).